# return не возвращает значение

Tags: java, return

Не могу понять почему метод say(String something) не возвращает "Ты чё не знаешь, что рыбы не разговаривают?"

Есть подкласс Fish

```
public class Fish extends Pet {
    int currentDepth=0;
    public int dive(int howDeep){
        currentDepth=currentDepth + howDeep;
        System.out.println("Ныряю на глубину " + howDeep + " футов");
        System.out.println("Я на глубине " + currentDepth + " футов ниже уровня моря");
        return currentDepth;
    }
    public String say(String something){
        return "Ты чё не знаешь, что рыбы не разговаривают?";
    }
}
```

Есть главный класс FishMaster

```
public class FishMaster {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fish myFish = new Fish();
        myFish.dive(2);
        myFish.dive(3);
        myFish.sleep();
        myFish.say("Привет");
    }
}
```

Есть супер класс Pet

```
public class Pet {
        int age;
        float weight;
        float height;
        String color;
        public void sleep(){
            System.out.println("Спокойной ночи! До завтра");
        }
        public void eat(){ System.out.println("Я очень голоден, давайте перекусим чипсами!");
        }
        public String say(String aWord){
            String petResponse = "Ну ладно!! " +aWord;
            return petResponse;
        }
    }
```

Есть главный класс PetMaster

```
public class PetMaster {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String petReaction;
        Pet myPet = new Pet();
        myPet.eat();
        petReaction = myPet.say("Чик!! Чирик!!");
        System.out.println(petReaction);
        myPet.sleep();
    }
}
```

Это весь код. Он взят с книги. В книге выводится строка "Ты чё не знаешь, что рыбы не разговаривают?", а у меня почему-то не выводится.

**Программа выводит:**
Ныряю на глубину 2 футов
Я на глубине 2 футов ниже уровня моря
Ныряю на глубину 3 футов
Я на глубине 5 футов ниже уровня моря
Спокойной ночи! До завтра

Comment: Почему вы решили, что он ничего не возвращает?

Comment: Что делает sleep? Как определён Pet?

Comment: Может подскажите, что поправить, чтоб вывелась строка "Ты чё не знаешь, что рыбы не разговаривают?" (ಥ﹏ಥ)

Comment: ```Fish myPet = new Fish(); ``` вместо Pet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка возвращается. Но Вы с ней ничего не делаете.

```
Fish myFish = new Fish();
...
System.out.println(myFish.say("Привет"));
```

Comment: О, большое спасибо ;)

Comment: @Makaroni Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: благодарю) а я как раз искал как закрыть вопрос =)